# Lazy Initialize Exception on Jackson Serialize with Hibernate 5 module configured

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I´m having trouble with the serialization to JSON by Jackson FasterXML when the member collection of a child element (i.e. a grandchild collection) is Lazily Initialized.

Here's an example of what the entities look like:

```
@Entity 
public class Parent {
 
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference 
    private List<Child> children; 

}
```

```
   @Entity 
   public class Child {

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FectchType.LAZY)
        @JsonBackReference
        private List<Parent> parent;
     
        @OneToMany(fetch = FectchType.LAZY) 
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<Grandchild> grandChildren; 

   }
```

The application is relatively large with a number of entities and many relations between them. It would be very slow if I was to either load everything eagerly or use the property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`. Instead the children of an entity required are loaded within the database transaction and everything else is laziliy initialized.

The exception that gets thrown on serialization is as follows:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: domain.Child.grandchildren, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->domain.Parent["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->domain.Child["grandChildren"])
```

Of course with this in mind what is needed is for Jackson to serialize those lazily initialized properties and member collections it finds as null - but I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

I´ve done research and found that there is a module to help with this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So I've configured Jackson as follows - but the exception remains.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {


    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configureObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();

        hibernate5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);
        hibernate5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION, false);
        hibernate5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.REQUIRE_EXPLICIT_LAZY_LOADING_MARKER, false);
        hibernate5Module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.WRITE_MISSING_ENTITIES_AS_NULL, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck! I don't know why the configuration I've provided isn't working.

Dependency information:

- Spring Boot `2.6.6`
- Hibernate `5.6.7.Final`
- Jackson `2.13.2`
- Jackson Datatype Hibernate5 `2.13.2`

Answer (score 0):

A custom filter that ignores a lazy fetched field

**Custom Filter**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
 
public class LazyFieldsFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return !Persistence.getPersistenceUtil().isLoaded(obj);
    }

}
```

**Using the filter**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = CUSTOMER_DB_TABLES.CUSTOMER_ORDER_PRODUCTS)
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = LazyFieldsFilter.class)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_method_id")
    private ShippingMethod shippingMethod;

}
```

credit: [JavaChina](https://www.javachinna.com/jackson-serialization-exclude-non-fetched-lazy-fields/)